# I can't break in Minecraft even if I click once on the move!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't break down stuff or kill animals I can't even if I click with one finger. I wish someone could help me.

Comment: "with one finger", can you expound on that?

Comment: Is this single or multiplayer? If multi, check permissions as sometimes only admins can break blocks.

Answer (score 12):

How are you trying to break stuff?

You have to keep holding the left mouse button until the block breaks and drops. If you just click then the "damage" you do resets and you'll never break the block.

You can only effectively break wood and dirt with your hand. For other block types you need tools.

The Minecraft Wiki has a [Beginner's Guide](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Beginner%27s_guide) which you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the left mouse button, until the item stops 'cracking' and breaks. You CANNOT do this with the touch pad (believe me, i have tried).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, for the touchpad method, have you tried double-tapping the touchpad, holding down your finger the second time (as you might if you were click-and-dragging)?

Comment: no, but that is an interesting question. I will check it out